# Validation of multiple inputs | HTML - jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, loops, validation

I have this inputs generated with php loop

```
<input type="text" name="input1" id="input1" class="input">
<input type="text" name="input2" id="input2" class="input">
<input type="text" name="input3" id="input3" class="input">
<input type="text" name="input3" id="input4" class="input">
```

I have this jQuery Code to check if any input is empty

```
if ( $('#input1').val() !== '' && $('#input2').val() !== '' && $('#input3').val() !== '' && $('#input4').val() !== '') {
    console.log("The inputs are not empty")
}else{
    console.log("One or more inputs are empty")
}
```

The inputs are generated by looping so the number of inputs changes, I want some code like this to do the validation, i tried this one but it did not work

```
if ( $('.input').val() !== '') {
    console.log("The inputs are not empty")
}else{
    console.log("One or more inputs are empty")
}
```

How can I do that? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$('.input')` will return more than one, but `$('.input').val()` can only return one value so it's only going to return the first value.  What you want is to loop over the inputs.  Something like this:

```
// set an initial value
var notEmpty = true;

// loop over the inputs and update the value if any are empty
$('.input').each(function () {
  if ($(this).val() === '') {
    notEmpty = false;
  }
});

// check the resulting value
if (notEmpty) {
  console.log("The inputs are not empty")
} else {
  console.log("One or more inputs are empty")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is because `$('.input')` returns a set of element (like an array).
One elegant solution is with `filter`:

```js
if ( $('.input').filter(function(){ return $(this).val() !== ''}).length > 0) {
    console.log("The inputs are not empty")
}else{
    console.log("One or more inputs are empty")
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="input1" id="input1" class="input">
<input type="text" name="input2" id="input2" class="input">
<input type="text" name="input3" id="input3" class="input">
<input type="text" name="input3" id="input4" class="input">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use loop below or use array methods like filter find etc...

```js
var empty=false;
jQuery.each($('.input'), function( i, val ) {if($(val).val() == '') {empty=true;}});
console.log(!empty ? "The inputs are not empty" : "One or more inputs are empty")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="input1" id="input1" class="input">
<input type="text" name="input2" id="input2" class="input">
<input type="text" name="input3" id="input3" class="input">
<input type="text" name="input3" id="input4" class="input">
```

or check directly value in query

```js
console.log(jQuery('.input[value=""]').length>0 ? "One or more inputs are empty" :"The inputs are not empty" )
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="input1" id="input1" value="" class="input">
<input type="text" name="input2" id="input2" value=""  class="input">
<input type="text" name="input3" id="input3" value=""  class="input">
<input type="text" name="input3" id="input4" value=""  class="input">
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a plain JavaScript solution:

```js
let isValid = false;
document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(input => {
      if(input.value !== ''){
        isValid = true;
      }
    });
    
    console.log('is this valid?', isValid);
```

```html
<input type="text" name="input1" id="input1" class="input">
<input type="text" name="input2" id="input2" class="input">
<input type="text" name="input3" id="input3" class="input">
<input type="text" name="input3" id="input4" class="input">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily with javascript ,
first of all put the inputs in form like this and add required to inputs

```
<form id="new_inputs">
   <input type="text" name="input1" id="input1" class="input" required>
   <input type="text" name="input2" id="input2" class="input" required>
   <input type="text" name="input3" id="input3" class="input" required>
   <input type="text" name="input3" id="input4" class="input" required>
</form>
```

then check it with javascript like this

```
var ni=document.forms.new_inputs;

if(ni.checkValidity()){
  console.log("The inputs are not empty");
}
else{
  console.log("One or more inputs are empty")
}
```

with this way the browser notify the user that the element required and its empty